# Not expected .map()/.match(regex) output

Tags: javascript, string, split

First line of the input contains an integer, N. Then N lines follow.
From the second line onwards, each line contains a set of W words separated by a single space.
For every line,
Print (console.log()) 1 if the conversation starts with hackerrank
Print 2 if the conversation ends with hackerrank
Print 0 if the conversation starts and ends with hackerrank
Print -1 if none of the above.

#### Code (JavaScript)

```js
const processData = (input) =>
  input
    .split("\n")
    .slice(1)
    .map((line) => line.match(/^(hackerrank)\b.*(?<!\bhackerrank)$/g) ? console.log(1) : line.match(/ hackerrank$/g) ? console.log(2) : line.match(/^(hackerrank)\b(.*(?<!\bhackerrank))?$/g) ? console.log(0) : console.log(-1));
```

#### Input

4
i love hackerrank
hackerrank is an awesome place for programmers
hackerrank
i think hackerrank is a great place to hangout

#### Expected output

2 1 0 -1
(one number by line... im having a hard time with my markdown)

#### The output I get

2 1 0 -1 -1
(one number by line... im having a hard time with my md)

what's going on with this last -1?
i've tested this code on codepen and it works but it doesn't work on hackerrank

thank you

Comment: Why does the expected output only have 3 numbers when there are 4 lines?

Comment: `'i think hackerrank is a great place to hangout'` does not match `/^(hackerrank)\b.*(?<!\bhackerrank)$/`, `/ hackerrank$/g`, or `/ hackerrank$/g`

Comment: @Unmitigated i'm having a hard time with the markdown lol. the expected output actually is >>>  2 1 0 -1 <<< one number by line. sorry for that

Comment: Try trimming the input. Perhaps there is an extra trailing newline.

Comment: @mongu `input.split("\n").slice(1).filter(Boolean)` to remove empty lines. Or `input.trim().split("\n")`.

Comment: @Unmitigated all tests passed. thanks a lot! ill try to fix my markdown now

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, so it should output 0 (third line). thanks

Comment: @code now i belive that was the problem. i fixed with .filter(Boolean) suggested by Unmitigated. now i don't get why on codepen it initial code worked. btw, thank you for your help

Comment: @mongu why should it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox "For every line, Print (console.log()) 1 if the conversation starts with hackerrank; Print 2 if the conversation ends with hackerrank; PRINT 0 if the conversation starts and ends with hackerrank; Print -1 if none of the above."

Comment: It seems to print -1 for "none of the above"

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, my mistake. so it prints -1 for "none of the above". my problem was the extra -1 printed after all the correct lines. thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove empty lines before parsing with `filter`.

```js
input.split("\n").slice(1).filter(Boolean)
```

Alternatively, remove leading and trailing whitespace from the input with [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) before splitting.

```js
input.trim().split("\n")
```